# regular expressions to capture repeated sentences

Tags: regex, csv, text, sentence

I've been doing some work with large text files recently.  I've transformed them into CSV format, with `|` as quotechar, but I've found that sometimes there are whole sentences that are repeated in the text file - not necessarily one after the other.  The sentences can be of varying length.  My aim is to remove duplicate sentences from the CSV file.  To clarify, it looks something like:

```
|something irrelevant|,|sentence1|  
|something irrelevant|,|sentence2|  
|something irrelevant|,|sentence3|  
|something irrelevant|,|sentence4|  
...  
|something irrelevant|,|sentence100,000|
```

where some of the second columns are repeats.  I have some experience with regex, but I haven't seen something that I could use for this.  Are regular expressions the right way to approach this, or is there a better alternative?  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you processing this with a programming language? Which one? In a text editor? Which one? In some other environment? Which one?

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm using python + sublime text 2, working with scikit.  I've just found an article that suggests importing the CSV to Excel and using it to remove duplicates.  I'll give that a try next.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I removed duplicate sentences from my text file as follows:

1. Transformed to CSV format
2. Imported to Excel
3. Use the "Remove Duplicates" function in Excel of the column that now contained the sentences
4. Export as CSV file
5. Convert back to text

This probably isn't the most efficient way to do things, but it works and it's very easy to follow through.  I'd wasted a lot of time writing complex regexes and messing around in python before, so hopefully this might save someone some time.